# Why does $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}dx$ diverge?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

So I've only seen the p-test for integrals:

$\int_0^1$ and $\int_1^{\infty}$

here:
http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/improper/testconv/testconv.html

but an example says that $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}dx$ is also divergent.

I would like to know, how to know this.

Comment: Because it diverges at zero *and* at infinity, by the p-test that you know...

Answer (score 3):

Among the power functions  $x\to x^\alpha$ ($x\in \mathbb{R^+}$), the case $\alpha=-1$ is an interesting limiting case.

For $\alpha>-1$, $\int_0^1 x^\alpha dx $ converges (and diverges for  $\alpha<-1$). Morally, you gain one degree in the primitive, so somehow $\alpha+1>0$, and the primitive with shape $x^{\alpha+1}$ behaves ok at $0$.

Conversely, when $\alpha>-1$, $x^{\alpha+1}$ tends to infinity when $x\to \infty$,  so  $\int_1^{+\infty} x^\alpha dx $ diverges.

So with power functions, you are either good at $0$ or $+\infty$, never at both. Except for $\alpha=-1$ where you get the worse of both worlds, too fast blow-up at $0$, too slow decay at  $+\infty$. 
The (c)onvergence or (d)ivergence with respect to $\alpha $ is summarized in this table:
\begin{array} {|r|c|c|c|}
\hline
\alpha& < -1& = -1 &  >-1\\
\hline
\int_0^1 x^{\alpha} dx&  \text{d}&  \text{d}&  \text{c}\\
\hline
\int_1^{+\infty}x^{\alpha} dx &  \text{c}&  \text{d}&  \text{d}\\
\hline
\end{array}

One of it primitive is $\log x$, and to some extend, the [logarithm is a twisted sort of unitless $0$th power function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13060/what-is-the-logarithm-of-a-kilometer-is-it-a-dimensionless-number/72464#72464).

Answer (score 1):

Semi-formally:
\begin{align*}
  \int_0^{+\infty} \frac{1}{x} \, dx
    &= \lim_{B \to +\infty} \lim_{A \to 0^+} \int_A^B \frac{1}{x} \, dx\\[0.3cm]
    &= \lim_{B \to +\infty} \lim_{A \to 0^+} \ln |x|\\[0.3cm]
    &= \lim_{B \to +\infty} \lim_{A \to 0^+} \left(\ln B - \ln A\right)\\[0.3cm]
    &= \lim_{B \to +\infty} \ln B - \lim_{A \to 0^+} \ln A\\[0.3cm]
    &= +\infty - (-\infty)\\[0.3cm]
    &= +\infty
\end{align*}

Comment: "f both are divergent then the sum can be divergent or convergent.." can it? in the riemann definition the integral is precisely the sum of those two components and it exists only if both converge. I think for the lebesgue integral we have something very similar (albeit I'm not sure). Maybe you're thiking about the cauchy principal value?

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I was thinking of series and not integrals.  Thanks, I'll remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to look at this is to notice that $$ \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx \ge \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{N=1}^M f_N(x) dx, $$

where $ f_N(x) = 1/N $ if $ (N-1) \le x \le N $ and $ f_N(x) = 0 $ otherwise. The integral $ \int_0^\infty f_N(x) dx = 1/N $ for each $ N \ge 1 $, so once you justify interchanging sum and integral (simply just by linearity of the integral), you see that

$$ \lim_{M \to \infty} \int_0^\infty \sum_{N=1}^M f_N(x) dx = \sum_{N=1}^\infty \frac{1}{N}. $$

This infinite sum is divergent because it is the harmonic series, so we see $$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x} dx \ge \sum_{N=1}^\infty \frac{1}{N} = \infty. $$

Comment: You don't really need to justify the interchange, you can write the integral as a sum over a 'partition' or $[1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\int_1^\infty \frac 1x dx$ were convergent, then by doing a change of variable $x=2t$, you would have
$$\int_1^\infty \frac 1x dx = \int_{1/2}^\infty \frac 1{2t}  2dt = \int_{1/2}^\infty \frac 1t dt = \int_{1/2}^1 \frac 1t dt + \int_1^\infty \frac 1x dx$$.

And so $\int_{1/2}^1 \frac 1t dt = 0$. But this is clearly impossible since $\int_{1/2}^1 \frac 1t dt \ge \int_{1/2}^1 1 dt = 1/2 > 0$

Answer (score 0):

For $0<a<b<\infty$, $\int_a^b\frac{1}{x}dx=\mathrm{log}b-\mathrm{log}a$. For $b\rightarrow \infty$ and $a\rightarrow 0$, it diverges to infinity.